# Do you put Frames in the mainloop() in tkinter?

Tags: python, tkinter

I am just learning Tkinter and I am wondering if you put `Frames()` in the `mainloop()`.

For example:

```
import Tkinter

root = Tk()
f = Frame(root)

root.mainloop()
f.mainloop()
```

Is this correct?

Comment: When you call the `mainloop` method of `Tk` class it's sufficient, because since `Tk` class is parent class of Frame, I think there's no point in calling 2 mainloops

Comment: @MrPedru22 Thanks, that helped!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should call `mainloop` exactly once for the life of your program. This is typically done via the root window.